# What is a person with no lower limbs called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose a person is either not born with legs or they have been amputated, what would he be called ?

I have heard "Amputee" but it is not specific, it does not imply that a person has no legs.

Comment: Perhaps legless?

Comment: Look up **apodal** or **double amputee**.

Comment: Most people would say "double amputee", and then qualify it in more detail if it seemed necessary.  Likely the folks who work with amputees and other disabled folks have more precise terms, but they would probably not be recognized by The Masses.

Comment: What do you call a dog with no legs?  It doesn't matter what you call him: _he ain't coming!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Legless](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/legless),* as Davo suggested in a comment:

> adjective
>   
> A legless person or animal has no legs.

([Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/legless))

Answer (score -1):

I've been a BBKA (Bilateral Below Knee Amputee), however,  BBK works, too.
What's really frustrating are the costs associated with prosthetics.

It's hard to get approval for better fitting prosthetics; which doesn't include residual limb physical changes.

The smallest weight gain or loss messes with your socket fitting, which leads us back to RLP (Residual Limb Pain).

I haven't slept in three days, because workers compensation won't approve Gabiapentin/Neurontin

Comment: I don't think that this term is what the OP is after.